# Tabularx and column overflowing

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I am trying to use tabularx to create a table that doesn't overflow the page horizontally, but I am now having issues with the values in columns overflowing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*{12}{{\RaggedRight \arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Statistics} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Speed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Depth} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distance to coast}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr) {8-10} \cmidrule(lr) {11-13}
 & OTB & PS & DRB & OTB & PS & DRB & OTB & PS & DRB & OTB & PS & DRB \\
\midrule
mean & 142.87 & 137.72 & 444 & 179.45 & 177.63 & 444 & -65.76 & -60.18 & 444 & 15021.19 & 6061.46 & 444 \\
STD & 102.94 & 190.15 & 444 & 109.92 & 104.11 & 444 & 42.37 &  36.11 & 444 & 14990.39 & 7907.20 & 444 \\
lower quartile & 102 & 3 & 444 & 91 & 95 & 444 & -84.76 & -81.74 & 444 & 4526.24 & 1377.05 & 444 \\
median & 113 & 12 & 444 & 175 & 175 & 444 & -56.71 & -61.33 & 444 & 8883.02 & 3657.02 & 444 \\
upper quartile & 145 & 381 & 444 & 277 & 270 & 444 & -38.18 & -33.4 & 444 & 212 & 7605.9 & 444 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB & PS fishing vessel types}
\label{table_statistics}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Image below shows my issue with values in columns overflowing as well as the horizontal lines not going to the end of the table:

[image]
How to fix this?

Comment: Please add a full preamle to your example code. Otherwise we don't know the `font size`, `margins` etc.

Comment: @marv Ok I added preamle.

Comment: Please make sure that your example does not depend on data we do not have access to otherwise we cannot test this. It seems that most of the settings from your example is irrelevant for your issue. Please make the example as short as possible (this is also a valuable debugging tool, reducing to the smallest example)

Comment: @daleif Alright, I edited my post and included the full latex code with the preamle that I copied into a new project. It only includes the table that i am having issues with. So you should be able to replicate my problem now.

Comment: Please make sure that the example actually compiles. The `array` package is missing, `{\RaggedRight \arraybackslash}` should be `>{\RaggedRight \arraybackslash}` and there is an unescaped `&` in the caption

Comment: You have a text width of 345pt and you need to accommodate 12 columns; this makes 144pt of intercolumn spaces, so you have just 301pt left; divide by 12 to get 25pt per column, just short of 9mm. A digit occupies about 5pt, so five digits already eat up the available space. And, of course, the first column is much wider than 25pt.

Comment: Quote from the black bible of typography: "_Tables are notoriously time-consuming
    to typeset, but the problems posed are often editorial as much as
    typographic. If the table is not planned in a readable form to
    begin with, the typographer can render it readable only by
    rewriting or redesigning it from scratch._" As Egreg already mentioned as the table is here you have way too much data for it to fit a normal text width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting issues, your table simply did not fit the available space. If you don't want to change font, decrease margin, or use another package (such as `tabularray` which I'd also recommend) etc., you could just move two other groups in the bottom part

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X *6{r}}
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Speed} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
        \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{OTB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{PS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{DRB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{OTB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{PS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{DRB} \\
        \midrule
        mean            & 142.87 & 137.72 & 444 &   179.45 &  177.63 & 444 \\
        STD             & 102.94 & 190.15 & 444 &   109.92 &  104.11 & 444 \\
        lower quartile  & 102    &   3    & 444 &    91    &   95    & 444 \\
        median          & 113    &  12    & 444 &   175    &  175    & 444 \\
        upper quartile  & 145    & 381    & 444 &   277    &  270    & 444 \\
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Depth} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distance to coast}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
        \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{OTB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{PS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{DRB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{OTB} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{PS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{DRB} \\
        \midrule
        mean            & -65.76 & -60.18 & 444 & 15021.19 & 6061.46 & 444 \\
        STD             &  42.37 &  36.11 & 444 & 14990.39 & 7907.20 & 444 \\
        lower quartile  & -84.76 & -81.74 & 444 &  4526.24 & 1377.05 & 444 \\
        median          & -56.71 & -61.33 & 444 &  8883.02 & 3657.02 & 444 \\
        upper quartile  & -38.18 & -33.4  & 444 &   212    & 7605.9  & 444 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
    \label{table_statistics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- your table code has error in caption. Instead of `&` should be `\&`
- table is quite wide, so probably you will have problem to fit it on page. In MWE below I assume, that page margins are 20mm and that you will agree with use of the `\small` font size in table.
- If this is not a case, than you have two options:

  - rotate table in landscape orientation
  - locally extend `\textwidh` with use of the `changepage` caption or use `\newgeometry` for page with this table

For table I would use `tabularray` (last version 2022B) instead `tabularx` and `siunit` package for `S` columns, which enable aligning numbers at decimal points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \sisetup{tight-spacing}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=2pt,
             colspec = {@{} c *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                               X[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                               X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]}
                            %
                               X[1.2, c, si={table-format=5.2}]
                               X[1.2, c, si={table-format=5.2}]
                               X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                        @{}},
             row{1,2} ={guard}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}  Statistics
    &\SetCell[c=3]{c}   Speed       &   &   
    &\SetCell[c=3]{c}   Heading     &   &
    &\SetCell[c=3]{c}   Depth       &   &
    &\SetCell[c=3]{c}   Distance to coast
                                    &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4} 
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-7} 
    \cmidrule[lr] {8-10} 
    \cmidrule[lr] {11-13}
        & OTB       & PS        & DRB
        & OTB       & PS        & DRB
        & OTB       & PS        & DRB
        & OTB       & PS        & DRB       \\
    \midrule
mean    & 142.87    & 137.72    & 444 
        & 179.45    & 177.63    & 444 
        & -65.76    & -60.18    & 444 
        & 15021.19  & 6061.46   & 444       \\
STD     & 102.94    & 190.15    & 444 
        & 109.92    & 104.11    & 444 
        & 42.37     &  36.11    & 444 
        & 14990.39  & 7907.20   & 444       \\
lower quartile 
        & 102       & 3         & 444 
        & 91        & 95        & 444 
        & -84.76    & -81.74    & 444 
        & 4526.24   & 1377.05   & 444       \\
median  & 113       & 12        & 444 
        & 175       & 175       & 444 
        & -56.71    & -61.33    & 444 
        & 8883.02   & 3657.02   & 444       \\
upper quartile 
        & 145       & 381       & 444 
        & 277       & 270       & 444 
        & -38.18    & -33.4     & 444 
        & 212       & 7605.9    & 444       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
\label{table_statistics}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]