# Multicolumn table - tabularray

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, tabularray

I would like to design a table like the one bellow, but I am not proficient enough in Latex and it would take me too long. Can someone help with writing a "mockup" table like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X *6{r}}
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{April} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{June} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
         & Cumulative Operating Time/h & Average Operating Time/h  & Cumulative Operating Time/h & Average Operating Time/h \\
        \midrule
        Trawler            & 142.87 & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87   \\
        Purse-seine             & 102.94 & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{September} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{October}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
             & Cumulative Operating Time/h & Average Operating Time/h  & Cumulative Operating Time/h & Average Operating Time/h \\
        \midrule
        Trawler   & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87  \\
        Purse seine             &  42.37 &  36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
    \label{table_statistics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed. Please show some code, even if imperfect, and people will suggest corrections and enhancements.

Comment: There's a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648342/tabularx-and-column-overflowing) about a similar table with the `tabularray`-based answer.

Comment: @Celdor Using your proposed solution from the question you are refering to i get overflowing texts (I edited this post so you can see what i mean). Is it possible to have everything in one line like the image i posted above?

Comment: I added my answer. While I was working on it, Mico and Bernard already gave you their suggestions so you can choose the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see no need for a `tabularray`, or even a `tabularx`, environment. Once you apply some reasonable abbreviations of the bloated header cell material, all 9 columns of the table fit within the width of the textblock. This suggests employing a 9-column `tabular*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{S[table-format=3.2]} }
    \toprule 
    Statistics 
    & \mc{April} & \mc{June} & \mc{September} & \mc{October}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
    & {COT\tnote{a}} & {AOT\tnote{b}} & {COT} & {AOT} & {COT} & {AOT} & {COT} & {AOT} \\
    \midrule
    Trawler      & 142.87 & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87 & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
    Purse-seine  & 102.94 & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87 &  42.37 &  36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[a]COT: Cumulative Operating Time, in hours
  \item[b]AOT: Average Operating Time, in hours
\end{tablenotes}
    
\caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
\label{table_statistics}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In contrary to @Mico, I see some advantages to use `tabularray` package :-). It define `talltblr` table, which is an equivalent to `threeparttable` with difference that tables' notes are written in table preamble. Using them, similar as @Mico done in his answer (+1) ,you can use in column headers abbreviations COT and AOT and tis way make columns narrower.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\NewTableCommand\SCC{\SetCell[c=2]{c}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types},
  label = {table_statistics},
note{a} = {COT: Cumulative Operating Time, in hours},
note{b} = {AOT: Average Operating Time, in hours},
                  ]{colsep = 3pt,
                   colspec = {@{} l *{8}{X[c, si={table-format=3.2}]} @{}},
                  row{1,2} = {guard, c}
                    }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Statistic 
1   &\SCC   April 
        &   &\SCC   June
                &   &\SCC   September
                        &   &\SCC   October
                                & 8 \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7} \cmidrule[lr]{8-9}
    & COT\TblrNote{a}   & AOT\TblrNote{b} & COT     & AOT   & COT   & AOT   & COT   & AOT   \\
    \midrule
Trawler      & 142.87   & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87  & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
Purse-seine  & 102.94   & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87  &  42.37 &  36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-)  When I wrote "I can see no need for...", I was referring to the fact that automatic line breaking is not needed in any of the table's columns. That's why I went with a `tabular*` envrionment instead, as it requires far fewer computation cycles to finish than a `tabularx` environment does.

Comment: @Mico,  Unfortunately, computation time is quite serious drawback of `tabutarray`. It is even longer as it is at `tabularx`.  "Classic" tables will be attractive for a long time to come.

Answer (score 1):

[image]This is quite easy with the `\thead` command from `makecell`, which enables you to have line breaks in standard columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X *6{r}}
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        \bfseries Statistics &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries April} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries June} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
         & \thead{Cumulative\\ Operating\\ Time/h} & \thead{Average\\ Operating\\ Time/h} & \thead{Cumulative\\ Operating\\ Time/h} & \thead{Average\\ Operating\\ Time/h} \\
        \midrule
        Trawler & 142.87 & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        Purse-seine & 102.94 & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        \bfseries Statistics &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries September} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries October}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
             & \thead{Cumulative\\ Operating\\ Time/h} & \thead{Average\\ Operating\\ Time/h} & \thead{Cumulative\\ Operating\\ Time /h} & \thead{Average\\ Operating\\ Time/h} \\
        \midrule
        Trawler & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        Purse seine & 42.37 & 36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
    \label{table_statistics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your table is the content; there is not enough space for that long headers. You can clearly see that! Also, a number of columns in definition must match a number of columns in the data.

There are two solutions. First, you could vertically split the long expressions usually by "inner `tabular`s" (see the code). Another option is to use a `\makecell{}` from a package `makecell`. Even though now the table fits the page, it is IMO not well balanced unless you have more data to add.

The other solution, which I think is slightly better, and the one you used in other question, is to use shorter texts or even use acronyms and add annotations at the bottom of the table

[image]

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\newcommand\tabcell[1]{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering

    \begingroup
        \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X *4{c}}
            \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
            Statistics & \multicolumn{2}{c}{April} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{June} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
            &
            \tabcell{Cumulative\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Average\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Cumulative\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Average\\Operating\\Time/h} \\
            \midrule
            Trawler     & 142.87 & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
            Purse-seine & 102.94 & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87\\
            \addlinespace[3pt]
            \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
            Statistics & \multicolumn{2}{c}{September} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{October} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
            &
            \tabcell{Cumulative\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Average\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Cumulative\\Operating\\Time/h} &
            \tabcell{Average\\Operating\\Time/h} \\
            \midrule
            Trawler     & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
            Purse seine &  42.37 &  36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
        \label{table_statistics}
    \endgroup
    
    \bigskip X \dotfill{} X\bigskip
    
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{X *4{c}}
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics & \multicolumn{2}{c}{April} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{June} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        & COT & AOT & COT & AOT \\
        \midrule
        Trawler     & 142.87 & 137.72 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        Purse-seine & 102.94 & 190.15 & 142.87 & 142.87\\
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        \toprule \addlinespace[6pt]
        Statistics & \multicolumn{2}{c}{September} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{October} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        & COT & AOT & COT & AOT \\
        \midrule
        Trawler     & -65.76 & -60.18 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        Purse seine &  42.37 &  36.11 & 142.87 & 142.87 \\
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{COT: Cumulative Operating Time/h} \\
        \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{AOT: Average Operating Time/h} \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Statistics of speed, heading and depth for OTB \& PS fishing vessel types}
    \label{table_statistics2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```